# How to get updated data from the server without reloading the page in web2py

Tags: python, ajax, database, web2py

I have made search bar functionality in a web2py application, getting results from a database. However, if the contents of the database are changed while the page is up, it needs to be reloaded to reflect the different content.
My question is how I can read the contents of the database into javascript variables without reloading the page, via ajax or json or somesuch.

Currently I use a controller like this:

```
def testDB():
        valA=[]
        valB=[]
        valC=[]
        for x in db().select(db.products.ALL):
            valA.append(x.prdA)
            valB.append(x.prdB)
            valC.append(x.prdC)
        return dict(VA=valA, VB=valB, VC=valC)
```

With a view fetching the data like so:

```
{{valA=VA}} {{valB=VB}} {{valC=VC}}
A = {{=XML(response.json(valA))}}
B = {{=XML(response.json(valB))}}
C = {{=XML(response.json(valC))}}
```

to use the variables. This works fine to use the data as it was when the page was loaded, but does not refresh to fit changes to the database. In order to fetch the new data, I tried:

```
function loadFromDB(){
jQuery.ajax({
type:"POST",
    url:'testDB',
    success: function(msg){      
    {{
    valA=VA
    valB=VB
    valC=VC
    }}
    A = {{=XML(response.json(valA))}}
    B = {{=XML(response.json(valB))}}
    C = {{=XML(response.json(valC))}}
    },
    error: function(errormessage){alert("Error in retrieving from database");}
 });}
```

But this seems to use the old VA/B/C variables, as it doesn't reflect any changes to the database. I've tried a few other ways, such as A=VA, outside of {{}} breackets, but haven't found the working one yet. How should I retrieve the data the python function returns into javascript?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your `loadFromDB` function is defined in the `testDB` view, then everything inside the `{{ }}` in `loadFromDB` will be filled in at the time the original page is created when `testDB` is called. The web2py template code does not get executed with the Javascript on the client side -- it is used to generate the initial Javascript on the server side (when the page is originally loaded).

If you want `loadFromDb` to do something with the data returned by the Ajax call, you'll have to write the logic in Javascript. Note, the jQuery.ajax `success` function takes the returned data as the first argument, so something like:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    [snip]
    success: function(data) {
        [JS code to do something with the returned data]
    },
    etc.
```

Comment: Could you give me an example of how to alert the returned data to the screen?

Comment: Something like `$('#target-element').html([some-part-of-your-data])`.

Comment: Just can't figure out how to retrieve the server-side python variable I want into a client-side JS one. Thanks for the help, though.

Comment: You'll need to return the data as JSON.